# How to identify a sound in python?

Tags: python, numpy, audio, multidimensional-array

Disclaimer: Forgive me if I missed something as I am new to sounds

I have a wav file which is a pure beep. I want to create a python program that listens through my microphone and every time it hears that same beep, it will act(i.e- print "heard").

I recorded that beep with silence at the start and end to make it more realistic. Next, I did this:

```
import noisereduce as nr
import librosa
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


# OG Loading
ogAudio, sampling_rate = librosa.load('.\\Beep.wav')

recordAudio, sampling_rate = librosa.load('.\\OneBeepRecord.wav')
noisy_part = recordAudio[0:25000]
reducedRecord = nr.reduce_noise(recordAudio, sampling_rate, False, noisy_part)
trimmedRecord, index = librosa.effects.trim(reducedRecord, top_db=35, frame_length=512, hop_length=64)
```

I picked `top_db=35` because the result's shape is the closest to the shape of `ogAudio`.

I figured that to 'compare' sounds I can use the correlation coefficients but I have different ndarray shapes as:

`print(ogAudio.shape, trimmedRecord.shape)`

Returns:

`(2981,) (2944,)`

To visualize(Blue is `ogAudio` and orange is `trimmedRecord`):

[Plotted Arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEVG8.png)

Is it possible that the record is shorter than the sound it self?

Comment: `librosa` is not defined, where does this come from ?

Comment: @D.L did not add imports to question. Editted

Comment: I think it might be better to look at the spectrogram of your beep, and act if the spectral content of what your program is hearing matches that spectrogram enough.

Comment: @AKX So basically I need to 'compare' spectograms? Do you have any references I can learn from?

Comment: Well, a spectrogram specifically is a visual display of a spectrum over time, but in general, you would take n-sample length chunks of your audio and run them through an FFT algorithm (if librosa doesn't have that, scipy does) to get a representation of the frequencies present. You'd then either compare it to your sample's spectrum or simply look for a peak at your beep's frequency.